# Triggers in mysql query error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am creating a trigger for mysql where when a user is registered then older value is replaced with +1 as new value for admin for showing new user registration.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `admin_notification_insert`
AFTER INSER ON `userss`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `admin-notification` 
SET  NEW.`notification-count` =  (OLD.`notification-count`+1) 
WHERE  `admin-notification`.`notification-id` =1;
END;
```

I have the errors in code as stated `#1363 - There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger`

What is the possible error in the query?

Comment: I think the error message is quite clearly worded. You're in an `INSERT` trigger. This means that you're dealing with a row that, until this moment, didn't exist in the table. As such, what do you *expect* `OLD` to provide you access to? Until you can explain that, answering would be a guessing game, since there seems to be a fundamental mis-step somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

With some search i was able to do it so i am answering this question myself too ...................

Link of mysource is [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) with the example there i able to solve particular `UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;`  help me alot. Code is below for my solution -

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `admin_notification_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `admin-notification` 
SET  `admin-notification`.`notification-count` = `admin-notification`.`notification-count`+ 1 
WHERE  `admin-notification`.`notification-id` = '1';
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`OLD` and `NEW` refers to the table on which the trigger is : `userss`  NOT `admin-notification`

You can try this:

```
UPDATE `admin-notification` 
    SET  `notification-count` =  (
        SELECT
            new_nc
        FROM (
            SELECT
                `notification-count`+1 as new_nc
            FROM
                `admin-notification` 
            WHERE
                `admin-notification`.`notification-id` =1
        ) as tmp
    ) 
WHERE  
    `admin-notification`.`notification-id` =1;
```

Comment: still showing the error when i replaced the sql query of mine with yours in trigger `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `admin-notification` 
    SET  `notification-count` =  (
        SELECT' at line 4 `

Comment: that is whole trigger i am using only one

Comment: i meant to show me the updated trigger with my query... the one that gave you that error

Comment: You are probably overcomplicating it. I'd expect the pattern to be just `UPDATE table SET column = column + 1 WHERE condition`.

Comment: @AndriyM goddammit ur right :| how blind was I ... thx man you should post the answer